# How to get item from array even if index is out of bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with 8 positions:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = "text1";
myArray[1] = "text2";
myArray[2] = "text3";
myArray[3] = "text4";
myArray[4] = "text5";
myArray[5] = "text6";
myArray[6] = "text7";
myArray[7] = "text8";
```

What I want to happen is if a user enters a number larger than 8 to get one of the texts from the array it starts from the beginning of the array again after [7]. So if the user whould enter 10, the user whould get the value of position [1] which is "text2". How whould I go about doing this?

Comment: `(input%MyArray.length)`? add one more if you're 1-indexed

Comment: write your own method and pass index to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could accomplish this via using the ["remainder" modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) which handles these kinds of "wrapping" scenarios :

```
function getArrayValueWithWrapping(array, index){
     return array[index % array.length];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `calculate` the remainder of `division`, using `% (modulos)` operator.

```js
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = "text1";
myArray[1] = "text2";
myArray[2] = "text3";
myArray[3] = "text4";
myArray[4] = "text5";
myArray[5] = "text6";
myArray[6] = "text7";
myArray[7] = "text8";
$('button').click(function(){
  alert(myArray[$('input').val()%8]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number"/>
<button>Get Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work with myArray[ index %8 ]. If you then try to call index nr. 8 the modulo returns 0. If you call nr. 9, it gets you index 1 of the array.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%` (modulos) operator.  This will take a number and divide it by another and return the remainder.  For example:

```
x = 9 % 8;
// x == 1
```

Because 8 / 9 = 8 with a remainder of 1, so this will never return a number greater than 8 but will cycle through the remainders (8 % 10 == 2, 8 % 16 == 0)